# Javascript / Ajax - Trigger event after redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have an AJAX function which triggers my function before the redirection at a URL. So, I need to trigger it later.

Here is the code, I will explain it below.

```
$('#backToLogin').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login/",
        success: function(result){
            $('#member-space').show();
            $("#form-container").html(result);
            console.log('success');
        },
        complete: function(complete){

        },
        error: function(er) { alert(er); },
    });
});
```

- **backToLogin** is the button on the first page which make the redirection.
- **member-space** is the DIV on the second page that I want to show but it's hidden. I have a button to show it but I want that DIV appear without any click event.

**PROBLEM** : The DIV **member-space** appears before the redirection.

Any idea?

Comment: Put `$('#member-space').show();` into setTimeout.

Comment: If I put a setTimeout, my DIV will appear before the redirection but slower, isn't it ?

Comment: WHich redirection do you mean, we don't see it in your code.

Comment: The URL part of the ajax method. I'm redirected to the login page with the hidden formular.

Comment: An ajax request on its own won't perform a redirect. Are you sure the page is not also posting back simultaneously when the click event is fired?

Comment: Taking into account the @ADyson comment, you should add a `e.preventDefault();` in event closure, to prevent default behavior of the `#backToLogin` buton